# Python list into a Python set and return the set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started coding. Need help with this. 
I have a list

```
A_list = [ 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

I need to make it into a set, now the catch is without using a set() function.

```
x =  [ 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
y = {}
for z in x:
    if z in y:
        continue
    else:
        y = x
        print(y)
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: set comprehension: `y = {z for z in x}`

Comment: could you mark correct answer that you like most? @حسن طاہر

Comment: Wait how do you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `y = {}`, you create an empty `dict`, not an empty `set`.
To create an empty set, you need `y = set()`.

For your exercise, you could store your unique values in a set (if you don't consider using `set()` to create the empty set cheating):

```
x =  [ 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
y = set()

for z in x:
    if z in y:
        continue
    else:
        y.add(z)  # you add your new unique element to the set 

print(y)
```

Or you can use a list:

```
x =  [ 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
y = []

for z in x:
    if z in y:
        continue
    else:
        y.append(z)  # you append your new unique element to the list 

print(y)
```

But of course, the efficient, not-an-exercise way would be to just write `y = set(x)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! when would I use y.update()?

Comment: For sets resp. dicts, to update them with the elements of another set resp. dict. Have a look at [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how strict is the expected task, but you can just do this (you are not using `set()`):

```
y = {element for element in x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
A_list =  [ 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
set_A_list = {*A_list}
```

About your error - you cannot create set with `y = {}` (empty braces). In that case the type of `y` will be `dict`. However, for example, `y = {1, 2}` will create a `set` (as it is **not** empty).

Comment: Brilliant! cheers man!